# EJS Tags inside JS Script tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am passing data from mongodb to front-end (EJS) using express. i am able to access the data in html using `<%= employee.name %>` , but the same thing gives an error when i write inside a script tag.

My express file

```
 res.render('traineepage.ejs', {
                employee: req.user
            });
```

my traineepage.ejs

```
<p><b>java marks</b> : <%= employee.marks.java %> </p>
```

this works fine, but

```
<script>
console.log(employee.marks.java);
</script>
```

this gives an error saying: `employee not defined`.

The script tag is written in the same file `traineepage.ejs`.

Comment: TLDR: ejs tags are resolved in the server context. script tags are resolved in the browser context. you can use ejs tags in your script file only *if it is processed in your server*. your html file is processed, so you could use ejs tags in there.